# segue getting twise call in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I have two view Controller one is **ScheduleController** and other is **EditShiftController**. In **ScheduleController** I have a table view name is **scheduleTable**. In the **scheduleTable** I have a cell with *identifier*  **ScheduleWithData**. In this cell i have two different button Button **EDIT** and Button **DELETE**. i have directly connected button **EDIT** with **EditShiftController** with segue *identifier* **editShiftSegue**.

The Code of **TableViewCell.swift**

```
var editShiftClick: (() -> Void)? = nil    
@IBAction func editShiftBtn(sender: AnyObject) {
    if let onButtonTapped = self.editShiftClick {
        onButtonTapped()
    }
}
```

The Code of **ScheduleController.swift**

```
myCell!.editShiftClick = {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("editShiftSegue", sender: dataTemp[indexPath.row].id)
        }
```

The function for prepareSegue in **ScheduleController.swift**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "editShiftSegue") {
        print("senderIndexPath=\(sender)")
        if (sender != nil) {
        let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! EditShiftViewController;
        svc.label = String(sender)
        }
    }
}
```

Snip Shot of Segue 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clcTh.png)

When I click on EDIT button then **EditShiftController** getting twice call I don't know why 
please, can any one help me here Thank you in Advance

Comment: What is the `onButtonTaped()` method in `TableViewCell.swift` ?

Comment: @Anthony Roani this the way to use Button click event in table view cell Thank you

Comment: What are you doing in this method ?

Comment: @AnthonyRoani  this the by default function of the swift which is fired when you clicked on the the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 myCell!.editShiftClick = {
        //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("editShiftSegue", sender: dataTemp[indexPath.row].id)
    }
```

Comment `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("editShiftSegue", sender: dataTemp[indexPath.row].id)` this line because if you have connected edit button directly with segue then no need to performsegue programatically also!!

**Update:**

```
  myCell!.editShiftClick = {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("editShiftSegue", sender: self)
    }
```

don't comment that line and delete that segue which is given from edit button. give segue from `viewcontroller to viewcontroller` and give identifier `editShiftSegue` and then perform segue as above code.

Comment: Answer Check i am trying to do, the twice call has been stope but now problem is how would i get the id which i was sending in 
............self.performSegueWithIdentifier("editShiftSegue", sender: dataTemp[indexPath.row].id)......... in this line

Comment: I am not getting your comment!

Comment: I was trying to send an id of an element with EDIT button click before uncommenting that line which you have told me i was getting the id but now i'm not getting it it's just simple going on EditShiftController

Comment: Answer Checked now i am getting this error 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<Work_Schedule.ScheduleController: 0x7fccabd30280>) has no segue with identifier 'editShiftSegue''

Comment: that means you have not set segue identifier properly. Ctrl + drag from VC to another VC to connect segue.  Then select that segue and from `attribute inspector` set identifier as `editShiftSegue` or else what you want to set and use same identifier in `performSegueWithIdentifier` method

Comment: and set sender as `self` or `nil` in `performSegueWithIdentifier` method

Comment: Answer Check i did set identifier and attached snip shot please see my updated question

Comment: Thank you very much for you time and your suggestion it's got fix here by the above solution i think i was missing something in that now it's working good.
as you can see i'm very new here so can't give you voting here if it's possible i will give you later thank you so much

Comment: you're welcome... :) You can accept the answer as `right tick` beside answer if you think that it is helping, so other people with similar issue can use it.